# dnf gave an curl handle error

Tags: fedora, package-management, dnf, yocto

Prerequisite:

- Linux: Yocto linux
- package-rpm
- dnf installed

My goal is to using dnf package manager, however when I try to run every option on dnf, it keep throws me python error like below.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/dnf", line 58, in <module>
    main.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 179, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 64, in main
    return _main(base, args, cli_class, option_parser_class)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 99, in _main
    return cli_run(cli, base)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/dnf/cli/main.py", line 115, in cli_run
    cli.run()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/dnf/cli/cli.py", line 1010, in run
    self._process_demands()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/dnf/cli/cli.py", line 763, in _process_demands
    load_available_repos=self.demands.available_repos)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 353, in fill_sack
    self._add_repo_to_sack(r)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/dnf/base.py", line 118, in _add_repo_to_sack
    repo.load()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/dnf/repo.py", line 916, in load
    handle = self._handle_new_remote(tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/dnf/repo.py", line 744, in _handle_new_remote
    h.setopt(librepo.LRO_PROXYAUTH, True)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.5/site-packages/librepo/__init__.py", line 1435, in setopt
    _librepo.Handle.setopt(self, option, val)
librepo.LibrepoException: (8, 'curl error: Error', 'An Curl handle error')
```

How to resolve this issue?
Thank you

Comment: There is an [ancient bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=998464) that leads to this error. If that doesn't fit your situation, have a look at the list of the other results when googling the error.

Comment: Thank you, actually I had read that bug fix too, but the way to reproduce the bug is bit different, thats why I ask in her. And I applied dnf here from poky yocto project thud. Hope I can found patch for this bug.